# java -version is giving me the version of openJDK installed, instead of JRE in $JAVA_HOME

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I have downloaded the java jdk from Oracle website and extracted it in the system. I have also don the entry of $JAVA_HOME to this one.

But I have to install dbeaver (sql client) software which also installs openjdk with it.

Now my system has two jres. OpenJDK and Oracle($JAVA_HOME). Whenever I am doing

```
java -version
```

It's giving me the version of that OpenJDK jre. Is it possible to make system use the Oracle jre(manually installed) instead of OpenJDK jre(keeping that installed in the system)

Comment: try `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: You could add your desired java binary directory to **PATH** environment variable. 
``export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin``

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: mmuzahid I have added the $JAVA_HOME/bin to the PATH environment variable. but still not using this java for

    java -version

Comment: @munish, did you reload your bashrc file after modifying PATH by running command something like that ``source ~/.bashrc``

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    whereis java
```

This will give you the path to the java binary as your system is finding it from the path.

If the path to the java binary is pointing to a different directory, then see the output of

```
    echo $PATH
```

You may find that the path to the OpenJDK bin directory is already in the PATH variable. You will need to remove this from the path.

Also, please do run the command given below to ensure that the alternatives have been updated correctly.

```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Follow the steps given here:
[How to install Oracle Java in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)